# do a recursive file compare for newness and report

Tags: ubuntu, files, scripting, recursive

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and have been using Dropbox over the years and found it solid in reliability.

Recently started using Zoho docs and like it, but I find its syncing flaky. I would like to continue using Dropbox for backup. The directory structure in my Dropbox has  been very thoughtfully organised. I have over 30,000 files and it helps me find what I want. I would like to keep a copy of my zoho docs files in the same directory structure as Dropbox.

Here is what I plan to do -

1. Create the same directory structure in zoho docs (no files, just structure). [Know how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073969/copy-folder-structure-without-files-from-one-location-to-another)
2. Create files in zoho docs in the same directory as I would like to see them in my Dropbox account. After creating a writer file (.zdoc) create a copy (.docx).
3. On a daily basics copy all the zoho docs content into dropbox, since they have the same structure. [Copy only if it has been updated](https://superuser.com/questions/341288/copying-a-file-only-when-it-is-newer-than-the-destination). Know how to do this.
4. Now the script I want is to check if I have remembered to save the .docx file. So I want to scan through the directories recursively, find .zdoc files and see if they have a corresponding .docx file which is newer. If not, then add it to a list and mail the list to me. Again can run this at a specific time daily. Having the docx will help me search in Dropbox in case I am looking for something.

Am looking for help on pt no: 4 only, but I put in everything there in case there is a better way of doing all of this.